# Integrable convex function vanishes at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convex-analysis

Why does a function that is Riemann-integrable in $[0, \infty)$ and that is convex vanishes at infinity?

Comment: Usually, the Riemann integral is only defined on bounded intervals, not on $[0,\infty)$.  Are you talking about a function whose improper Riemann integral exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convex function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ has a limit as $x \to \infty$. This limit is possibly $\pm \infty$. Show that if such a function $f$ is (improperly) Riemann integrable then the limit must be zero.

---

Added on edit: every (or just about every) notion of convergence has a corresponding Cauchy property. In the case of the improper Riemann integral, you have that if$$\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b f(t) \, dt$$ exists, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $M > 0$ with the property that
$$ M < a < b \implies \left| \int_a^b f(t) \, dt \right| < \epsilon.$$  (The converse is true, too). If $f$ has a nonzero limit, the quantity $$\left| \int_a^b f(t) \, dt \right|$$ can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $a$ and $b$ large enough. Thus a nonzero limit is incompatible with the Cauchy property.

Comment: I stopped typing my answer because I think this is cleaner, but OP might not know how to show that the limit of a convex function as $x \to \infty$ always exists (although might be $\pm \infty$).

Comment: Your answer is confusing. You said the limit at $\infty$ is $\pm\infty$ and $0$ on the same time ...

Comment: @user251257 you missed the word "possibly"

Comment: oh, you are right. I am sorry.

Comment: I mean, it's pretty obvious to show the limit always exists if the function is twice differentiable because then we know $f''(x) \geq 0$, which is enough to show that either the function is always weakly decreasing, or at some point becomes always weakly increasing, so the limit exists (allowing for $\pm \infty$, of course). But a convex function doesn't even have to be continuous.

Comment: @user2566092 if $f$ is nonincreasing then it must have a limit. On the other hand, if there exist $x < y$ with $f(x) < f(y)$, then convexity implies $f \to \infty$.

Comment: Indirectly assuming the limit is not zero, i.e. there exits $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. for all $R \in \mathbb R \quad \exists x > R: |f(x)| \geq \varepsilon$. How does this contradict the improper Riemann-integrability?

Comment: @Mekanik you should be able to work out the details. Think about the "area under the graph" -- if the limit is nonzero can it be finite?

Comment: @Mekanik The point is that Umberto P is claiming that the limit always EXISTS, whereas your counterpoint seemed to only claim that the limit is not zero, without taking into account that the limit exists. If the limit is some finite $y \neq 0$ (or, $\pm \infty$) then clearly the integral does not converge.

Comment: @UmbertoP What you're saying is that if a convex function increases by a certain amount over an interval, then it must increase by at least the same amount over the next interval of the same size, by convexity. I get that, but still if I was back when I was just taking calculus or intro real analysis, I might not be able to see that right away. At any rate, I think these comments have given enough details to OP to make your answer work.

Comment: ok, I get it intuitively but dont know exactly how to write down a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Mekanik I some comments on edit.